# Libreoffice: How to install Portuguese dictionaries after and before the Orthographic Agreement at the same time and select the one I want?

Tags: libreoffice, dictionary, spell-checking, hunspell

There's an Orthographic Agreement for the Portuguese (pt_PT) language but some places won't accept the new gramatical spelling and force me to write in the old way.

Libreoffice has both dictionaries [LibreOffice Dicionários](https://pt.libreoffice.org/descarregar/dicionarios/) but when I install one, it overwrites the other one. And I want to use both, depending on the document.

I know MS Word allows you to select if you want the portuguese spelling with or without Orthographic Agreement.

So, the question is: **Is there any way or workaround to have both dictionaries installed and select the one I want in a per document basis**?

For example, maybe creating some kind of pt_PT_PREAO and pt_PT_AO locales and copying the original files? If that's possible, how to do that?

**INFO**

- Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS
- LibreOffice 6.0.7.3

Comment: Information added as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to solve this is to install both extensions, Portuguese PRE-AO and Portuguese AO, and disable the one you don't want to use for a given text.

In that case, the spelling will be according to the enabled dictionary.